# Rate-limiting promises in mapping over large array

Tags: javascript, arrays, asynchronous, queue, promise

I am currently trying to feed in the array phoneNumbers below.  The example array has 2 phone numbers, which works fine, but my actual array contains thousands of numbers.

When I try to use promise.all and map the phone numbers to a name, I get a connection error because it is taking so long.  How do I use promises (or something similar) to do maybe like 50 or 100 at a time in the array?

```
var phoneNumbers = [4444444444, 5555555555];

var answer = client.Answer;
return Promise.all(phoneNumber.map(id => Answer.findThing(id, {
    attributes: ["name", "state"]
}))).then(problems => {
    for (var p = 0; p < problems.length; p++) {
        var phoneNames = problems[p].name;
    }
})
```

Comment: What does `Answer.findThing()` return?  Where is the connection error occuring?  There's no connection error in this code so I don't know why you think this code would be the cause?  How many `phoneNumbers` are in your actual array that you're trying to lookup?

Comment: I've fixed the two syntax errors in your code, I guess they were typos only?

Comment: What promise implementation are you using? Many libs have custom functions that help you deal with exactly this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading between the lines, it would appear that you want to return a promise of an array of names.

If so, you can tidy the code as follows :

```
// ES6 native Promise
// n parallel requests
var phoneNumbers = [4444444444, 5555555555, ...];
var findOptions = { 'attributes': ['name', 'state'] };
return Promise.all(phoneNumbers.map(id => client.Answer.findThing(id, findOptions))).then(problems => problems.map(p => p.name));
```

That's just tidying, not a solution.

If the length of the `phoneNumbers` array is indeed the source of your error, then you need to try throttling the number of simultaneous pending `.findThing()` requests. The simplest way to do this (at least diagnostically) is to use Bluebird's [.map()](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.map.html) with its `concurrency` option.

```
// Bluebird
// n requests but a maximum of 10 (or whatever) concurrently
var phoneNumbers = [4444444444, 5555555555, ...];
var findOptions = { 'attributes': ['name', 'state'] };
var mapOptions =  {concurrency: 10}; //adjust up/down experimentally
return Promise.map(phoneNumbers, id => client.Answer.findThing(id, findOptions), mapOptions).map(p => p.name);
```

The same effect *can* be achieved with native Promise, but the code would not be quite so neat.

If you find that only `{concurrency: 1}` works, then Bluebird's `Promise.map` is overkill. Sequential requests are simple to code using native Promise :

```
// ES6 native Promise
// n sequential requests, by building .then chain
var phoneNumbers = [4444444444, 5555555555, ...];
var findOptions = { 'attributes': ['name', 'state'] };
return phoneNumbers.reduce((promise, id) => promise.then(() => client.Answer.findThing(id, findOptions)), Promise.resolve()).then(problems => problems.map(p => p.name));
```

That may be too memory hungry; if so then a recursive alternative would be better :

```
// ES6 native Promise
// n sequential requests, through recursion
var phoneNumbers = [4444444444, 5555555555, ...];
var findOptions = { 'attributes': ['name', 'state'] };
function find(index, results) {
    return (index < phoneNumbers.length) ? client.Answer.findThing(phoneNumbers(index), findOptions).then(p => {
        results.push(p.name);
        return find(index+1, results);
    }) : results;
}
return find(0, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
var promises = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < phoneNumbers.length; i++) {
                (function () {
                    var def = new $.Deferred();
                    promises.push(def);
                    var j = i;
                    asyncFunction(phoneNumbers[j]).then(function (data) {
                        //do whatever here
                        def.resolve();
                    })
                })();
            }
            var completePromise= $.when.apply(undefined, promises).promise();
```

When completedPromise is resolved you know that all of your phone numbers have been processed by ______ asyncFunction. It should allow for many to be processed at the same time, although I've only ran this code in production with a few hundred not thousands.